# openssl recover signed file

Tags: openssl, certificate, sign

I have some signed files that I would like to modify and then re-sign.  I need to recover the signed_file to the unsigned state.  The files were signed like this:

```
openssl smime -sign -in myfile.txt -out signed_file -signer mycert.crt -inkey mykey.key -certfile my-chain.crt -outform der -nodetach -passin file:mypass.pwd
```

Is there an openssl command that will do the recovery?
Could I just strip off the header and footer of the signed files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
openssl smime -verify -in signed_file -inform der  -noverify
```

This only works on an unencrypted, signed file.